# Ext.Viewport.add doesn't work well without centered true value

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch, extjs6

I wish that a button from my toolbar create panel on the mainview
I use this:

```
{
                text:'toolbarButton1', //my button
                cls: 'grbuttons',
                ui:'action',
                height: 95,
                width: 95,


                handler: function() {


                    Ext.Viewport.add({
                        xtype:'mapWorkSpace',
                        centered:true,
                        layout:'float',
                        cls:'toolbars',
                        height: 500,
                        width: 300,
                        draggable: false,
                        scrollable:true,
                        margin: 800
                });
                }
```

but when centered config has false value, 'mapWorkSpace' renders somewhere i can't found ( a panel is invisible on the mainview).
How to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle? Where is your xtype 'mapWorkSpace' defined? Without more details and information it is difficult to give help on this.

Comment: @aallord , thank you for a reaction. 'mapWorkSpace' is defined in different js file ('Fiddle.Mapworkspace' class). files with code https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2op2